# Одиночка в разных namespace действительно ли одиночка?

Tags: ооп, php, проектирование

Есть несколько namespace в приложении, и в каждом из этих namespace лежит класс singleton (одиночка), название класса от одного namespace к другому не меняется. Вопрос: экземпляр этого класса будет на каждый namespace свой или единый для всех namespace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вообще тут нужно понимать, что если у вас есть такие классы:

```
namespace First
{
    class Foo 
    {

    }
}
```

и

```
namespace Second
{
    class Foo 
    {

    }
}
```

то имя каждого из классов, это не просто Foo, а First.Foo и Second.Foo, это два разных класса с разными полными именами. точно так же как Вася Сидоров и Вася Табуреткин  - это два разных человека, несмотря на то, что обоих зовут Вася. 
 А что касается синглтонов, то их "единственность" зависит исключительно от правильности реализации паттерна, а не от пространств имен, в которых находятся классы. Более того, экземпляры классов вообще никак не соотносятся с пространствами имен, в которых объявлены классы, вне зависимости от того, синглтон это или нет. Экземпляр не может быть "один на namespace" или "несколько на namespace" - такая постановка вопроса вообще бессмысленна

Comment: А если они оба наследуются от некого общего одиночки, из третьего namespace (глобального)?

Comment: @Андрей Таланин, то они все равно объявлены каждый в одном неймспейсе, но существуют в среде в целом.

Comment: >А если они оба наследуются от некого общего одиночки, из третьего namespace (глобального)?

повторю на всякий случай еще раз: экземпляры классов вообще никак не связаны с пространствами имен. Это касается как синглтонов, так и любых других класов